# Using where clause in constraint or check constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, unique-constraint

I have a requirement where unique constraint should be based on certain condition.
If the status column is "LIVE" it should not allow another live record for the same algo_id.
When I put unique constraint on this two column it does not allow to add multiple "OLD" status record.

```
TABLE: ALGO
ID : Number(10)  -- PK
Algo_id              VARCHAR2(30)      NOT NULL,
Status          VARCHAR2(30)     NOT NULL,

Algo_id  Status
ALGO-123 OLD
ALGO-123 OLD
ALGO-123 LIVE
ALGO-234 REMOVED
ALGO-234 REMOVED
ALGO-234 LIVE 
ALGO-234 LIVE <This should not allow as there is already live record for ALGO-234>
```

Thanks is advance.

I have tried below

```
ALTER TABLE ALGO
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_live_algo UNIQUE (algo_id, stats );
```

Is there way where I can put some condition like below:

```
ALTER TABLE ALGO
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_live_algo UNIQUE (algo_id, stats ) where/when Status = 'LIVE';
```

Comment: Make a trigger to implement the logic

Comment: Side note: Prefer integers over strings in the case you have to cover only a specific set of values, they are less error prone (consider case mismatches, for instance), more performant to look up and require less storage and memory.

Answer (score 3):

Some databases support `WHERE` in a constraint definition, but Oracle does not seem to support this.  However, we can try using a unique function based index here:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx1 ON ALGO (
    CASE WHEN Status = 'LIVE' THEN algo_id END,
    CASE WHEN Status = 'LIVE' THEN Status END
);
```

For those records *not* having a status of `LIVE`, both values in the tuple would just be `NULL`.  Since Oracle allows multiple `NULL` values with a unique constraint, therefore duplicates would be allowed.  Otherwise, a unique constraint would be applied to `(algo_id, Status)`.

I give credit to this excellent [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/212379/table-check-contraint-to-verify-unique-on-specific-value) question/answer which solves this problem.

Comment: `status` is redundant here, because it will contain constant value (`LIVE`) for this particular code.

Comment: @astentx Sorry, I don't follow your comment.  When the status column has `LIVE` as the value, we want to apply a unique constraint to the tuple `(algo_id, Status)`.  Otherwise, we don't want such a unique constraint.

Comment: @astentx means you just need `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx1 ON ALGO (CASE WHEN Status = 'LIVE' THEN algo_id END);`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, so `CASE WHEN Status = 'LIVE' THEN Status END` will not add more uniqueness, because it maps wider range into two values: `null` (which will not be indexed, because entire tuple becomes a tuple of `null`s for this case) and `LIVE`, which corresponds to the same original value (1-to-1).